# Как исходя из URL выполнить скрипт?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вопрос, на странице есть переключатель табов
Можно ли составить ссылку таким образом что бы исходя из ссылки при переходе нужный таб был открыт
Пример

```
site.ru/page#one
site.ru/page#two
site.ru/page#thr
```

Т.е в зависимости от ***#one, #two, #thr*** открывался нужный таб
Вопрос, как в JS получить вот это значения...

Comment: `<a href="#one">Tab one</a>`  ,    `<div id="one">i tab one</div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Document.location**](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/location)

Доступное только для чтения свойство `document.location` возвращает объект Location, который содержит информацию о URL страницы и предоставляет методы для изменения этого URL и загрузки другого URL.

Используя его Вы можете достичь желаемого, вот пример:

```
<div id="one">
<div id="two">
<div id="three">

<script>
    let params = document.location.href.split('#');
    if (params.length > 1) {
        let pageId = document.location.href.split('#')[1];
        document.querySelector('#' + pageId).classList.add('active');
    }
</script>
```

Если в строке браузера будет `site.ru/page#one` то `<div id="one">` получит класс `active`